# "Whatever you can do today, don't postpone it to tomorrow"

Tags: word-requests, chengyu

I just learned a German proverb:

> "Was du heute kannst besorgen, das verschiebe nicht auf morgen,"

which can be translated as:

> "Whatever you can do today, don't postpone it to tomorrow"

Is there a 成语 or 古语 which has the same meaning?  I might use it in the context of encouraging someone to not procrastinate.

Comment: web search using "关于拖延的成语" will yield many 成语 expressing procrastination in different words, Linguee: There's no time like the present. jukuu: **机不可失,时不再来。** 
Procrastination is the thief of time.拖延为时间之贼

Answer (score 5):

> *"Whatever you can do today, don't postpone it to tomorrow"*

1. This common Chinese saying may had the same origin as the quote in the question:

> "**今天的事今天做**"
>
> "**Don't put off till tomorrow what you can do today**."
>
> *This phrase is so common, it is in grade school textbooks*
>
> variant: **今日事今日做**

2. The idiom 坐言起行 express a similar sentiment in a stronger sense.

> "**坐言起行**"
>
> **Once decided, act immediately**; **When plan is formulated, implement it without delay**

3. There's also a common Chinese expression expressing the similar sentiment

> "**有花堪折直須折**, (莫待無花空折枝)"
>
> "**Pick the flower when it is time** , (don't wait til there's no flower but stem left to be picked.)"

Original poem:

> *金縷衣(七言樂府詩)*
>
> *勸君莫惜金縷衣，勸君惜取少年時。*
>
> *花開堪折直須折，莫待無花空折枝。*
>
> *作者: 杜秋娘*
>
> *Gold Linen Jacket (seven words Yuefu poem)*
>
> "*You should not cherish gold linen jacket, you should cherish youthful days.*"
>
> "*Pick flower when it blooms, don't wait til there's no flower but stem left to be picked.*"
>
> *Author: Du Qiuniang*

Side note :

A completely opposite sentiment expressed in another poem is also very famous.

"今朝有酒今朝醉，(明日愁來明日憂)"

"Drink when you have wine today, (worry about tomorrow's problems when tomorrow comes)"

Original poem:

> *唐·罗隐*
>
> *得即高歌失即休，多愁多恨亦悠悠。*
>
> *今朝有酒今朝醉，明日愁来明日愁。*

Answer (score 2):

今日事，今日毕。

Here 今日 means "today's" or "... of today". 事 means things in general, and 毕 means finish. So altogether, it means, literally but somewhat awkward in English, "Finish the things to be done today within today".

Answer (score 0):

> 明日复明日, 明日何其多.
>
> 我生待明日, 万事成蹉跎.

Tomorrow and tomorrow, tomorrow there are too many.

I wait for tomorrow all my life,  and all things can not be done.

明日歌, A famous poem written 钱鹤滩

> 今日复今日，今日何其少！
>
> 今日又不为，此事何时了.

Today and today, today is too less.
Not do it today, when will be done

今日诗, written by 文嘉